# Are the Area 51 Beta core user statistics cumulative per rank?

Tags: discussion, reputation, area-51

On each Area 51 proposal in Beta, we see something similar to:

> Okay – Every site needs a solid group of core users to assist in moderating the site. We recommend:
>
> ```
> 150 users with 200+ rep (on pace for 107 users at 90 days)
> 10 users with 2,000+ rep (on pace for 11 users at 90 days)
> 5 users with 3,000+ rep (on pace for 5 users at 90 days)
> ```

I get that the '+' indicates "rep and up", but for some reason the manner of presentation feels like it should exclude any that count for a higher requirement.

Are the 5 users with 3,000+ rep counted in the 2000+ rep total requirement?

Are the 10 users with 2,000+ rep counted in the 200+ rep total requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 200+ rep - Users with 200 rep and above (even with 2,000 or 3,000+)
>
> 2000+ rep - Users with 2,000 rep and above (even with 3,000+)
>
> 3000+ rep - Users with 3,000 and above

So, Yes. the 5 users (if up to 5) with 3000+ rep are counted in the 2000+ rep, the 10 users (if up to 10) with 2000+ rep are counted in the 200+ rep total requirement.